# Why does the classList.contain() keeps returning false?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why does the classList.contain() keeps returning false? I want to create a toggle effect. when on click, only the descendent of a certain class will have the toggle effect. However, the containing method keeps returning false.

One weird part when I'm playing around with the containing method is when I take out the '.classList' it returns True perfectly. But I know if I want to find descendent classes of their parents I need '.classList'. Why is this?

Here is my HTML.

```
               <ul class = "horizontalpic">
                   <div class = 'fakebutton'>
                        <div class = 'starsolid'>
                            <i class="fas fa-star fa-s" style = color:black></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </ul>
```

JS

```
const starhover = () => {
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
    document.querySelector('ul.horizontalpic').addEventListener('click', e => {
        console.log(e.target);
        console.log(e.target.classList.contains('starsolid'));
    });
});starhover();
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` your `e.target.classList` and you'll see that it's `horizontalpic`, not `starsolid`.

The reason for that is because when you click on that element then you're clicking on the parent element, not the child.  You've added `document.querySelector('ul.horizontalpic').addEventListener('click'` to that element, `starsolid` likely won't be triggered on any click.

If you want to fix it then change your click event to the correct element.

`.contains` will check any descending child element, so if you call it on `e.target`, which in this case is `horizontalpic`, it will loop through `fakebutton` and `starsolid` and find it.

Comment: when I 'console.log' my 'e.target.classlist' it returns DOMTokenList ["fakebutton", value: "fakebutton"]. Because the element that I clicked on will be passed into the event handler. Which in this case is fakebutton. I did call the '.contain' on 'e.target' but it returns false.

Comment: Yoiu're contracting yourself from your question where you mentioned ````when I take out the '.classList' it returns True perfectly````, now you're saying that it suddenly returns false, most likely because you used ````.contain```` and not ````.contains````.  If you call ````.contains('starsolid')```` on ````e.target```` it should be true, no matter if it's ````horizontalpic```` or ````fakebutton````.  Don't use ````.contains```` on a string like ````classList````, in this case you only need ````e.target````.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding here. I did say that it returns True when I take out `.classList`. But it's not supposed to work, because `contains()` is used to determine whether a node is a descendant of another node. Now I'm determining whether an element contains a class, which needs `.classList` to achieve this.

Comment: I mentioned this `But I know if I want to find descendent classes of their parents I need '.classList'. Why is this?` in my question

Comment: No there's no misunderstanding.  "But it's not supposed to work" -> Incorrect, it is supposed to work, that's exactly what ````.contains```` is made for.  ````.contains```` will find decendent children of an element based on classname or element tag.  "I know if I want to find descendent classes of their parents I need "'.classList'." -> You're incorrect, you don't need to, just use ````.contains````.

Comment: okay. just based on curiosity, so `.contains()`method can determine elements both in the form of Nodes and classes without `classList`  right?

Comment: You can use ````someElement.contains('div')```` too if you want, or you can use ````someElement.contains('.someClass')````, both of which will automatically find any descendant child.

Answer (score 0):

[Code Pen Solution](https://codepen.io/_tashi_/pen/RwVqNBo)

your `console.log(e.target);` is pointing to `<i class="fas fa-star fa-s" style = color:black></i>` which does not conatin the class 'starsolid'. Therfore, it always console logs False.

Comment: 'console.log(e.target);' is actually pointing to the element that I clicked on. For example, if I click on fakebutton,  'console.log(e.target);' will return '<div class = 'fakebutton'>...</div>

Answer (score 0):

try this:

keep everything same only change this row on your code.

```
console.log(e.target.classList.contains('starsolid') || e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('starsolid'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer checks if the clicked element contains the className, if the parent contains it or if any of the children and children of the children contains it:

```js
const functionmy = () => {
  const className = 'starsolid'
  document.querySelector('ul.horizontalpic').addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log(e.target.classList.contains(className) || e.target.parentNode.classList.contains(className) || Object.values(e.target.getElementsByTagName('*')).map(e => (e.classList)).some(arr => (Object.values(arr).includes(className))));
  })
}

const starhover = () => {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', functionmy);
};


starhover();
```

```html
<ul class="horizontalpic">
  <div class='fakebutton'>
    <div class='starsolid'>
      <h1 class="fas fa-star fa-s" style=color:black>hello</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</ul>
```